# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions .jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a java plugin to an application that I'm using (I didn't write it and don't have the source) that connects to my MySQL database...the only problem is that anytime I try to load the application I get a communication link failure

17:51:57 [INFO] Could not create connection: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
17:51:57 [INFO] Database initialization failed: java.lang.NullPointerException

I have verified that all of my mysql settings are pointing to the correct port that I'm giving this plugin and I've also checked to make sure the user I created for this has privileges over the database it's going to be modifying. I'm out of ideas and it never times out, I would think it was the plugin but the plugin has many users and they use the plugin with MySQL just fine and I continue to have the problem after reinstalling the plugin.

I'm sure it's an issue with MySQL but as far as I can tell...everything is fine, so any clues about what would cause this would be great. I've been reading around and the stuff I've seen didn't help the issue.

### SOLUTION

for UBUNTU and MySQL 5.1: Added mysqld : ALL to /etc/hosts.allow

Comment: Which OS you are using? Version of MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, it was ubuntu and the version was 5.1. I fixed the problem by adding mysqld : ALL to my /etc/hosts.allow.

Comment: @ark3typ3, feel free to add the solution as an answer to your own question. You may even accept your own answer in due time!

Comment: I also found another solution for this problem at http://webexpertsconsulting.com/2012/02/using-mysql-with-jdbc4-on-mac-with-mamp/
i hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for UBUNTU and MySQL 5.1: Added mysqld : ALL to /etc/hosts.allow